# Set center of dynamic size image

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I'd like to be able to set the absolute (x, y) position for the center of a dynamically sized image with JS. There must be some arrangement of CSS containers that would allow for this, but I haven't been able to figure it out. One could use a JS calculated offset, but it makes animated scaling rather complicated, so I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Please show some of the HTML/CSS that you tried, and set up a demo in http://www.jsfiddle.net and welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks, I will clean it up and post. Investigating transform-origin.

Comment: That's a while since I last saw the word arraignment. It's not used correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution.

HTML:

```
<div id='parent'><div id='child'></div></div>
```

Child CSS:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Setting a translate on the parent will now move the child by its center.